# Java method override/interface problem

Tags: java, interface

I have

```
interface FooI
class FooA implements FooI
class FooB implements FooI
class FooC implements FooI
```

I wrote a class "Handler" that has the following methods

```
static double handle(FooA f)
static double handle(FooB f)
static double handle(FooI f)
```

and I have a function like the following:

```
void caller(FooI f)
{
    Handler.handle(f);
}
```

with f just being known as a class implementing FooI. However f is an instance of FooA

Instead of calling the method for FooA, the method for FooI is called.

When I use f.getClass().getName() I get the correct class name (FooA).

I am confused because I expected the best-suited method to get called, namely the one for FooA.

I wanted to use the FooI method as a fallback to handle classes that could be implemented later, and I also want to handle f without having one big function where I am doing **instanceof** checks for all currently known classes implementing my interface.

What would be a good approach to do this?

Comment: Thanks for the additional tags, Samuel :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Overload resolution is done at *compile time* rather than *execution time* in Java. The signature was picked based on the compile-time type of your variable. Only *overrides* are determined at execution time.

A common solution for this in languages like Java is to use [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) and the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Personally I'm not a huge fan of this. I prefer to try to design my way around it. That's not always possible, of course, but it's worth at least attempting.

Comment: Just by curiosity...why don't you like these patterns ?

Comment: Thanks a bunch Jon! I totally forgot about the whole resolution issue.

Comment: @LB I can't vouch for Jon, but I personally find them to be rather ugly because now there's a bunch of indirection and boilerplate in front of what is, conceptually, a very straightforward operation.

Comment: It's amazing how often this question is asked and answered.  I bet there have been at least a couple of hundred points in reputation score attributed to this question.  I only got 10 of em  :-(

Answer (score 3):

You expect that the JVM seaches for the best fitting method **at run time** but that doesn't happen, actually. Instead the method to call is selected during compile time, when the only known information is that f is a class that implements FooI.

The best approach for that problem, the one that avoids the instanceof checks, might be moving the "handle" method into those classes FooA, FooB, FooI.

Comment: Thanks ammoQ! I totally forgot about that :-(.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what your design is, but might the 'handle' functionality be better placed in your concrete FooI implementations?

Comment: Thanks teabot, that's how I implemented the whole thing in the end :-).

Answer (score 1):

Java resolves which method to call at *compile time* using the *reference type*, which in your example is `FooI` - if you think about it this makes sense as the *reference type* is all it really has to go on at *compile time*.

Your `Handler` class doesn't `handle(FooI f)` and so as far as the compiler is concerned there is no valid `handle` method to call.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use a static method for that, static methods obey to other rules than non final instance methods

Comment: The static-ness is irrelevant here. The point is that it's *overload* resolution which is taking place, not *override* resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You could transform your interface into an abstract class, with a handler implementation. Then you implement it, and FooA and FooB overrides it